# MODULE_NOT_FOUND: ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am getting this error when i did ionic serve. Can anyone explain? Tried to update npm install still getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Delete node_modules folder and re-install node dependency 
npm install

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: Were you even in your ionic project folder when you did ionic serve? ie. is Silver_Helpers your project folder? And did you install the ionic cli globally with npm install -g? ie. you do ionic start <project folder>.. then cd <project folder> and do ionic serve

Comment: Yes i am aware that you have to be in your project folder to do ionic serve.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I was able to fix it. My environment is mac but try this

1. npm i
2. if it asks update ionic-cli, select Y
3. npm rebuild node-sass

At step 3, I got exact message to rebuild sass.